# org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP - for only one page in my project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mapping

i have a simple spring application and there are many post about this issue but i am not able to see where i wrong. I am not able to view displayAllOrders.jsp as mapping not found is displayed. :(

Please find below my web.xml mapping:

```
<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/pres.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet> 

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Please find below pres.xml:

```
<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
    infrastructure -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.pres" />
<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="validator"
        class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
```

Please find below my controller(package:com.example.pres):

```
@Controller
public class OrderController {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(OrderController.class);

@Autowired
OrderService orderService;

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET,value="/displayAllOrders")
public ModelAndView listPeople() {
    logger.debug("Received request to list orders");
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    List<Order> order = orderService.getAllOrders();
    logger.debug("Order Listing count = "+order.size());
    mav.addObject("order",order);
    mav.setViewName("displayAllOrders");
    return mav;
}
```

Please find below the href tag in the page home.jsp(Path:src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\views\home.jsp) page that calls displayAllOrders.jsp(Path:src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\views\displayAllOrders.jsp):

```
<a href=displayAllOrders> View order</a>
```

I am able to display the home page, but when i click on the hyperlink displayAllOrders:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/project/displayAllOrders] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
```

Any ideas why my mapping is not working for displayAllOrders please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try adding controller specific request mapping and change anchor tag href attribute with ${contextPath}/your-mapping for method.

Answer (score 0):

Your url mapping is for `/displayAllOrders` not for `/project/displayAllOrders`, please change the `RequestMapping` in the controller and try.

Comment: Hello thanks a lot for the response.. just in case of someone else have this issue,i have closed eclipse and started again and now its working fine without any changes made to the code..i guess eclipse was playing around :)..thanks again for the response.